# Why is it behaving this way?

Tags: javascript

When is run this, its printing undefined. while doing the `ret.push(func(arr[i]))` it does have the context right ?

```
        function print(arr,func){
             var ret =[]
             for(let i =0 ;i<arr.length;i++){
                  ret.push(func(arr[i]))
                 }
             return ret;
        }
        var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
        console.log(print(numbers,(x)=>{x+1}));
```

it prints [undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined].

Comment: Looks like `func` is not returning anything ..?

Comment: Your arrow function does not return anything.

Comment: You're not returning anything from `func()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a `return` statement and get the new values.

```js
function print(arr, func) {
    var ret = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        ret.push(func(arr[i]));
    }
    return ret;
}

var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(print(numbers, (x) => { return x + 1; }));
//                                  ^^^^^^

// or take a simplified lambda with implicit return (kudos paul!)
console.log(print(numbers, x => x + 1));
```

Comment: Note that you'll also get an implicit return if you remove the curly braces:  `x => x + 1`

Comment: Yes, it was supposed to be without curly braces. Thanks for reminding that. @Paul. Such tiny detail makes a lot of difference. That's why i love JavaScript :D